# Odd periodic function with fundamental period $3$

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ is an odd periodic function with fundamental period $3$ , then what is the value of $f(45678)+f(123456789)$

Comment: How did you get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Notice that $45678$ and $123456789$ are both multiple of $3$. Check that this is true.

Hence $$f(45678)+f(123456789)= 2f(0)$$

Now we know that $f$ is an odd function.

What values can $f(0)$ take? Can you complete this?

Comment: f(0) = 0. It is not exactly given.

Comment: good job. you solved the problem